# Google Map Key & Google Places Key. <metadata> Tag issue Android

Tags: android, google-maps, metadata, api-key, google-places

i have two different keys: one for Google Place and other one for Google Map. When I declare both on `<metadata>`, it shows the below error. are there any solutions and if so, please recommend these.

`error -- The API key can only be specified once. It is recommended that you use the meta-data tag with the name: com.google.android.geo.API_KEY in the <application> element of AndroidManifest.xml.`
[image]
Note: I don't want to use single Api-Key

Comment: Are they under `<application>` tag ?

Comment: @MD yes within the <application> tag.

Comment: Please check [this](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/get-api-key). You don't need to add 2 API keys in manifest.xml file i think

Comment: @M D i have gone through your link, but i can't do this, client wants to use different Api keys for map and places.